# Merge with Overlapping columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

If I have two data frames that contain data during the same period (although no necessarily for the exact same dates) and I want to merge them together. The data can be thought to look like this:

```
import datetime, random
import pandas as pd

dates = [datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 1, 2), datetime.date(2014, 1, 3)]
IDs = ['1001', '1002', '1003']
name = ['john', 'james', 'jim']
data1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in xrange(9)]
data2 = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in xrange(6)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : dates * 3,
                   'ID'   : IDs *3,
                   'name' : name * 3,
                   'data1': data1})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : dates[:2] * 3,
                    'ID'   : IDs[:2] *3,
                    'name' : name[:2] * 3,
                    'data2':data2})
```

The merge is to be performed on the data and ID columns as follows:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['date', 'ID'], how = 'outer')
```

In this situation obviously I get name_x and name_y in the resulting dataframe. What I would like to know if there is a way to have the resulting dataframe only contain one name column, and the values of the column will be the non NaN value found in what would be either name_x or name_y.

Formulated another way, is there a method to use merge such that when performing and outer merge, in the resulting data frame where an inner merge would 'fail', to keep the value that is not null?

This of course assumes that the name would have to be the same in df1 and df2 where an inner merge would succeed. I know this to be the case.

For the case of Jim, I get this output:

```
      ID  data1        date name_x  data2 name_y
18  1003     13  2014-03-01    jim    NaN    NaN
19  1003     98  2014-03-01    jim    NaN    NaN
20  1003      8  2014-03-01    jim    NaN    NaN
```

But I want is this:

```
      ID  data1        date   name  data2
18  1003     13  2014-03-01    jim    NaN
19  1003     98  2014-03-01    jim    NaN
20  1003      8  2014-03-01    jim    NaN
```

I know that I could easily do this after the merge:

```
merged.name = merged.name_x.fillna(megred_y)
```

But this is a pain as in the real data I have many columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built-in to merge to have the behavior you're describing.  But, as you note, it shouldn't be that big of deal to handle after the fact.

If you've got many columns, could you handle the replacements by iterating over the columns, as below?  You could wrap this in a function and handle in a single step.

```
columns_to_fix = [c.rpartition('_x')[0] for c in merged.columns if c.endswith('_x')]
for c in columns_to_fix:
    merged[c] = merged[c + '_x'].fillna(merged[c + '_y'])
    merged = merged.drop([c + '_x', c + '_y'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Cool! Never seen partition or endswith. I was iterating previously, but I like those two little extras...